# Nosuchmethoderror:org.glassfish.jersey.internal.l10n.LocalizableMessageFactory

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

I m working with jersey2.29 and Spring 4 to develop a web application. The following are my dependencies.

[image]

When starting Tomcat server 8 server, it doesn't start and I get the following error

> Caused by: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.l10n.LocalizableMessageFactory.(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/l10n/LocalizableMessageFactory$ResourceBundleSupplier;)V**
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.LocalizationMessages.(LocalizationMessages.java:19)
>               at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(SpringWebApplicationInitializer.java:46)
>               at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
>               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>               ... 6 more

I tried adding all the latest jar files in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: show all your jersey related jars in classpath

Comment: here is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVmWV.png

Comment: try using jersey-spring3 instead of jersey-spring4, also what's your spring version?

Comment: I m using spring 4

Comment: Is it `4.3.8` or above?

Comment: I m using spring 4.1.4

Comment: Why do you have a Jersey 2.26 jar (jersey-common) in there? Don't mix your Jersey versions. Where did that even come from?

Answer (score 0):

You not have minimal dependency for [jersey-spring4](https://jersey.github.io/project-info/2.28/jersey/project/jersey-spring4/dependencies.html) which is Spring 4.3.8

> org.springframework    spring-aop  4.3.8.RELEASE   jar Apache License, Version 2.0
>
> org.springframework    spring-beans    4.3.8.RELEASE   jar Apache License, Version 2.0
>
> org.springframework    spring-core 4.3.8.RELEASE   jar Apache License, Version 2.0
>
> org.springframework    spring-web  4.3.8.RELEASE   jar Apache License, Version 2.0

You should use spring-jersey3 jar

Comment: still the issue prevails even after using jersey spring3 jar

Comment: @GnanambalMeyyappan see its dependencies https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3/2.19